# Python eval expression all permutations for arithmetic operators

Tags: python, eval, combinations, permutation

Given `string = '1*7/5-3'`

I have expression to evaluate the string like  `eval('1*7/5-3')`

Code :

```
import __future__
string = '1*7/5-3'
print eval(compile(string, '<string>', 'eval', __future__.division.compiler_flag))
```

I want to evaluate for all permutations

```
example 
        eval('((1*7)/5)-3') 
        eval('1*((7/5)-3)')
        and so on
```

Comment: Try creating a list of numeric values and a list of operations. Try creating a function that returns the result when the operations are evaluated in a specified order: my_eval(list_values, list_ops, order_ops) where your order_ops=[1,2,3] is your first example and order_ops=[2,3,1] is your second example given. Seems like a good candidate for recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have edited it to eliminate the "extraneous" parentheses.  They were in fact, necessary.  I'm reverting to the original code.

The idea is to consider each operator symbol in turn as the main operation -- the root of the [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree). This splits the string into two parts, and we apply the procedure recursively.

```
 def parenthesize(string):
    '''
    Return a list of all ways to completely parenthesize operator/operand string
    '''
    operators = ['+','-','*','/']
    depth = len([s for s in string if s in operators]) 
    if depth == 0:
        return [string]
    if depth== 1:
        return ['('+ string + ')']
    answer = []
    for index, symbol in enumerate(string):
        if symbol in operators:
            left = string[:index]
            right = string[(index+1):]
            strings = ['(' + lt + ')' + symbol +'(' + rt + ')' 
                           for lt in parenthesize(left) 
                           for rt in parenthesize(right) ]
            answer.extend(strings)
    return answer    

 string='4+7/5-3'
 for t in parenthesize(string):print(t, eval(t))
```

This prints

```
(4)+((7)/((5-3))) 7.5
(4)+(((7/5))-(3)) 2.4
((4+7))/((5-3)) 5.5
((4)+((7/5)))-(3) 2.4000000000000004
(((4+7))/(5))-(3) -0.7999999999999998
```

BTW is this for Euler Project problem 93?